# Modifying button colors via SPFx is not being reflected

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, modern-experience, spfx-webparts, calendar

I am working on this SPFx web part @ https://github.com/pnp/sp-dev-fx-webparts/tree/main/samples/js-modern-calendar.

Now when I click on a event inside the calendar, I will get this dialog box with a blue OK button:

[image]

I am trying to change the background color for the button from blue to red, So I tried to modify the following `.scss` files:

[image]

But still the button is been displayed in blue, any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This modern calendar SPFx web part sample uses [sweetalert2](https://sweetalert2.github.io/) library for showing dialog/popup.

"OK" button on dialog inherits CSS from `sweetalert2.min.css` file.

To change the background color of OK button, you have to override the below CSS classes in your web part CSS:

[image]

Follow below steps:

1. Create `swal-override.scss` file inside `modernCalendar` folder
2. Add below CSS in `swal-override.scss` file:

   ```
   button.swal2-confirm {
       background-color: red !important;
   }
   ```
3. import this file in `ModernCalendarWebPart.ts` file using:

   ```
   import './swal-override.scss';
   ```

---

**Update from comments**:

If above CSS is not working for you, try adding `confirmButtonColor: "#FF0000"` inside `modalOptions` in `ModernCalendarWebPart.ts` file.

For example:

```
let modalOptions: swalalert.SweetAlertOptions = {
  title: _event.title,
  html: eventDetail,
  showCloseButton: true,
  width: '800px',
  confirmButtonText: "OK",
  confirmButtonColor: "#FF0000"
};

Swal.fire(modalOptions);
```

Comment: so did yo add the custom css inside the `.EmptyCalendar` main class?

Comment: Try adding it inside `.EmptyCalendar` at the end/bottom side. If it is not working for you, add it outside of this block.

Comment: what you did in your case? as you provided a screen shot of the result. thanks

Comment: your code did not work for me,i tried placing the css inside multiple locations but nothing changed

Comment: In SPFx, I use separate CSS files to override library CSS with my custom styling. Check updated answer & let me know if this works for you.

Comment: yes creating `swal-override.scss` file inside modernCalendar folder fix the issue.. thanks