# I am using the js-modern-calendar but I want to change the background color for Today block inside the calendar

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, modern-experience, spfx-webparts, calendar

I am working on this SPFx web part @ https://github.com/pnp/sp-dev-fx-webparts/tree/main/samples/js-modern-calendar but I want to change the background color for Today block to different color:

[image]

How I can achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To change the background color of Today's date cell in calendar, you have to override the below CSS classes in your web part CSS:

```
td.fc-day.fc-today {
    background-color: aqua !important;
}
```

**Output**:

[image]

Follow steps given in this thread to know more about how to override CSS: [Modifying button colors via SPFx is not being reflected](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/302786/modifying-button-colors-via-spfx-is-not-being-reflected)

Comment: You can also try solution given [here](https://therichpost.com/change-day-background-color-fullcalendar-particular-date/) & check if it works for you.